# Django queryset - Return only matching manytomany records when applying filter on object

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I cannot seem to figure out a way to limit the manytomany elements returned when applying a filter on an object. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help with this.

Let's say I have the below models:

```
## models.py

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Venue(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    venues = models.ManyToManyField(Venue)
```

Now if I have one event that will be going on at two venues and one event at one venue as follows (simplified for illustrative purposes):

```
e1 = Event1
e2 = Event2

v1 = Venue1
v2 = Venue2

e1.venues.add(v1,v2)
e2.venues.add(v1)
```

I would like to generate a queryset that would bring back all events going on at 'Venue1' with only 'Venue1' as the returned venue with those events.

I have tried

```
event_list = Event.objects.filter(venues__address__city='CityVenue1')
```

but 
    event_list[0].venues.all()

returns both 'Venue1' and 'Venue2'.

My preference would be to:

1. Filter the Event object in the view rather than the Venue object.
2. Not to apply any logic via tags/filters in the template and leave it to the view to return the needed queryset for performance
   reasons.

My template iterates through the event list as follows:

```
{% for event in event_list %}
    <p>event.name 
    {% for venue in event.venues.all %}
         at {{ venue.address.city }}
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like it to return:

```
Event1 at CityVenue1
Event2 at CityVenue1
```

but currently I get

```
Event1 at CityVenue1
       at CityVenue2

Event2 at CityVenue1
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you're getting back both venues, you're querying all venues from your template.

```
{% for venue in event.venues.all %}
```

This line performs a brand new query, grabbing all venues for the event.

Instead; in your view, do your filter and explicitly pass on the venue you're interested in:

```
target_venue = Venue.objects.get(address__city='CityVenue1')
event_list   = target_venue.event_set.filter(name='EventName')

return render(request, 'events/event-list.html',
    {'Events': event_list, 'Venue': target_venue})
```

Then in Your template,

```
{% for Event in Events %}
    <p> {{ Event.name }} at {{ Venue.address.city }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Improved via suggestion from @limelights

Comment: This is good, but you could simplify it a bit with `target_venue.event_set.all()` instead of filtering on the Event model further.

Comment: @limelights from the question, it's obvious that he only wants Events that meet certain criteria, not all events. `I would like to generate a queryset that would bring back all events going on at 'Venue1'`. Therefore, the filter is necessary.

Comment: According to docs, `event_set.all()` should work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Apologies @limelights, you are right. I misread your comment to mean Event.objects.all(). I've updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @ Thomas-limelight...Won't that get all events for that venue. What if I want to filter the events based on other elements such as 'name'. I am trying to filter on both sides i.e. show only events that match a certain criteria and also return only the venues (street, city, state) matching the searched location i.e. city/state? I may be asking for too much. Another possibility that I have considered is returning a list of tuples that have the event and a list of matching venues based on the location filter like [(Event1,[Street1-CityVenue1, Street2-CityVenue1]), (Event2,[Street3-CityVenue1])].

Comment: @BinaryMaze, then filter the event list as much as you need. `target_venue.event_set.filter(whatever_filter_values)`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want that all in one queryset ?
`Venue.objects.get(id=<id_venue1>).event_set.all()` should return you all the events linked to venue1 in one queryset, and you can have venue1 in another queryset.

---

You can also use
`Venue.objects.get(id=<id_venue1>).values('adress', 'phone_number', 'event__name', 'event__description')` to get something like the array of dicts bellow:

```
[
  { 'adress': '<venue1adress>', 'phone_number': '<venue1phone>', 'event__name': 'foo', 'event__description': 'I am a foo event'},
  { 'adress': '<venue1adress>', 'phone_number': '<venue1phone>', 'event__name': 'bar', 'event__description': 'I am a bar event'},
  ...
]
```

---

Finaly , I think, you can also rework the default queryset (since it's a python objects, and with python objects you can do anything you want):

```
events_for_venur1 = Event.objects.filter(venues=venue1)
for event in events_for_venur1:
  for venue in event.venue_set:
    if venue != venue1:
      venue = None
# Here your queryset is ready, but DO NOT try to save it in the DB !!
```

Comment: `event <-> venue` is a m2m relation, you wont get back the dict you expect. Also, messing with the queryset in that way is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't see the warning in Django doc at the end of the .values() documentation..